# C++ write and read from mysql database

Tags: c++, mysql, database, windows

I'm working on a project where we want to write to a mysql database, I've googled around and tried a few implementations but they all fail.

For example I tried this: http://markalexanderbain.suite101.com/using-a-mysql-databases-with-c-a70097

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "libmysql")
#pragma comment(lib, "mysqlclient")
using namespace std;

MYSQL *connection, mysql;
MYSQL_RES *result;
MYSQL_ROW row;
int query_state;

int main() 
{mysql_init(&mysql);
//connection = mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"host","user","password","database",0,0,0);
connection = mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"localhost","bainm","not_telling","cpp_data",0,0,0);
if (connection == NULL) 
cout << mysql_error(&mysql) << endl;
return 1;
}
```

It compiles and generates an exe file, but it closes every time I try to run it, I've added a cin.get at the end so it wouldn't close.

But the program still closes and Visual Studio 2010 gives me the following error message: The program '[32856] mysql test.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).

The only thing that is common in all these implementations is the Include files and the   #pragma comment(lib, "libmysql") and    #pragma comment(lib, "mysqlclient")
I'm using these files which are included with mysql ga 5.5.16 32 bit.

So I'm looking for a way to write to a mysql database, if any one knows how to fix this to make it work or knows another way with a tutorial please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error code 0xc0000135 means "The Application Failed To Initialize Properly".  This is almost certainly due to a missing DLL (or two); probably the ones relating to MySQL mentioned in your `#pragma lib` statements.

Either add them to your path or copy them to the same directory as the .exe.

EDIT: Follow the instructions from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/building-clients.html), in order to compile with the correct options.  The file `mysqlclient.dll` should be included with the MySQL installation (do a system file find if you cannot find it).

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find the mysqlclient.dll does anyone know where I can find it?

Comment: Yes, if you statically link to the library.